# How to get FireFTP to work with Waterfox browser

Tags: waterfox, fireftp

A year or more ago, I first downloaded, installed, and had FireFTP addon working fine under the Waterfox browser, on a 5-year-old laptop, running Windows-10 64-bit.

So, I recently purchased a new laptop, with Windows-10 64-bit pre-installed.

On both laptops, I have Chrome as my primary browser, along with Opera and Firefox, and Edge all operational (I'm a web developer and test web-pages on the various browsers).

I install Waterfox browser solely because I've come to know and love the FireFTP add-on, for uploading web content to a web-server.
(Formally, I used FireFTP addon under FireFox browser, but approx a year ago, due to revised architecture of Firefox, the FireFTP addon no longer is compatible with Firefox, and the suggested fix/workaround is to use the Waterfox browser, since Waterfox IS compatible with Waterfox.)

But, on the new laptop, for some unknown reason, I can get FireFTP addon downloaded, and installed upon Waterfox browser, but I can
NOT get FireFTP to create the account needed to connect to my
(same) web-server.  The exact symptom is that the dropdown in upper left corner of the FireFTP tab says: "(Choose an account)", but clicking on that does nothing. I see no way to specify/configure a (new) account, with the connection-info to communicate with a web-server.

The version # of my add-on downloaded is: fireftp-2.0.4-fx.xpi

The version # of Waterfox browser is: 56.2.6 (64-bit).

What am I missing???

Comment: I am using FireFTP 2.0.31 with WaterFox 56.2.6 and it works perfectly. You need to find an update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of FireFTP. User @AFH is correct, you needed to install the latest version of FireFTP to continue.

User @Dave the link you provide is to a site that I cannot endorse and could have compromised code. The correct link to find the latest release is here: https://github.com/mimecuvalo/fireftp/releases

It used to be hosted on addons.mozilla.org but since Firefox doesn't support FireFTP anymore, the official listing there was deactivated.

Happy to assist further if you need it!

Comment: Are you sure?  I get "There aren’t any releases here"

Answer (score 0):

MANY THANKS to user AFH, whose comment above led me directly to the
solution!

A simple google search of "FireFTP 2.0.31" revealed exactly where to go
to get the needed newer version...namely, here:
    https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/fireftp/#gref

EDIT: Yes, as shown in the answer below, I have downloaded a newer version,
namely 2.0.32, from https://github.com/mimecuvalo/fireftp/releases
[ Thanks for that addional info. ]

Cheers...

Comment: The first link is no good, and the second link download cannot be installed on the latest version of Waterfox. It says the file is corrupt.